# Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type using laravel-echo package in angular

Tags: angular, laravel-echo

i created a `channel` and i able to send `event` (`broadcast`) from `laravel` backend, now i want to `listen` by `angular`, but it gives me many error: `Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type`

**app.component.ts**

```
    constructor(){
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit() : void {
    const echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: '9d80a4aa39484cd65055',
      cluster: 'mtl',
      wsHost: window.location.hostname,
      wsPort: 6001,
      forceTLS: false,
      disableStats: true
    });

      echo.channel('chat')
      .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
          console.log('chat event data : ', e);
  });  
  }
```

and also `Vcode` underlines with e ,see image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the type of input data:
For example, the (e:any)